# Better or Not combine Search Engine and Recommend System?

Tags: search, machine-learning, ranking, recommendation-engine

In our project, we use search engine, but the result need to be ranked based on each user's interest, similar to recommendation according to users' keyword.

If we separate the two system, it would cost a lot time.

Is there a better way to combine Search Engine and Recommend System together?

Or is there a simple way to customize my ranking strategy to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what we were trying to do in our project as well. There are two things while solving this problem - Relevancy vs Personalization. You should look at how much of personalization is ruining the relevancy of the query. For example, if I'm suggesting news, then it makes sense to suggest based on location. I hope you already would have analyzed the use cases.

The way that I followed was - after getting the results on the search, then re-rank results to give personal suggestions. For example if I was searching for a specific algorithm to code, then getting the result set and re-ranking on my preference, lets say on, Java (based on my previous history) will make sense. In any case relevancy is of utmost importance and then we fit in user's preferences.

Again the use case is important, if this was for a news search, then directly querying and retrieving on location is best way to do it.

Comment: However, if we get the results on the search, then re-rank results based on user's interest. It may cause none of the results fetch from the first step meet user's taste. How did you deal with it?

Comment: Thats true. So the users data is important. You could use topic modelling on the first step results to see if they match with the users data. Topic modelling because, they will relate the results semantically. So even if the user is searching for oops and java was his preference(which you can capture through his clickstream), topic modelling will get a match.
More importantly, if his preferences don't match the search results even remotely there is no point in re-ranking and you just serve the results as it is.