# How do recommender systems and search engines work together?

Tags: search-engine, recommendation-engine

When a user searches on a website like Tripadvisor, does the system filter the items with the user's input first and then the recommender system decides the order of the results?

In other words: is the output of the search engine the input of the recommender system?

Wouldn't this leave out some relevant items for the user because it doesn't consider her preferences? Also the diversity of the results may be affected.

In this question [Better or Not combine Search Engine and Recommend System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844372/better-or-not-combine-search-engine-and-recommend-system) they mention to use topic modeling. But I think this would represent a lot of changes to my system.

So, how do real recommender systems deal with this problem? Do they "relax" the search? Is it done before or after the search?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to this problem is to use a hybrid recommender system, which consists of many approaches running simultaneously (usually on a distributed environment). The outputs of each approach is combined somehow, forming the final result. Some example of how this could be done are:

- weighted - each approach gets a number of votes
- cascade - one approach identifies candidates, another ranks
- mixed - take n results from each system

There are many more. Also, context should be considered as an input, and the exact hybrid method (including parameters) learned either from historic data or online testing.

Comment: But what would be the relation between the hybrid recommender and the search engine? Another problem is that if the recommender ranks the output of the search engine, it could place on the top some irrelevant items for the search because it's considering the user's tastes and not how much the item matches the search.